# Rails belongs_to is not explicitly required, but the model demands it. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My `Account` model only has one `not null` field under my control: `account_type` and after setting it, it still won't `.save`, demanding a valid `.user`. Any ideas why?

```
>> a = Account.new
>> a.account_type = :user
>> a.valid? #=> false
>> a.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 => false 
>> a
 => #<Account id: nil, balance: #<BigDecimal:7f23fc3e2d68,'0.0',9(18)>, account_type: "user", user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
>> a.errors.messages
 => {:user=>["must exist"]}
```

Furthermore, adding a valid user to the `Account` makes it validate:

```
2.3.1 :023 > user = create(:user) # factory girl creates this for me
2.3.1 :024 > a.user = user
2.3.1 :025 > a.valid?
 => true
```

But `Account.user` shouldn't be required!

Here's the entire model including schema:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: accounts
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  balance      :decimal(, )      default(0.0)
#  account_type :integer          not null
#  user_id      :integer
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#

# accounts and their associated balances
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions

  enum account_type: {
    user: 1,
    deposit: 2,
    withdrawal: 3,
    fees: 4
  }
end
```

### Enum clarification

While it may look like `account_type` is a string, but it isn't. If you read the model, I've actually mapped enum values on it, which is pretty nifty since it allows me to send and receive strings/symbols to the model, but is saved as an integer in the database, making search faster.

Read more [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Comment: Your account_type is not getting valid input. Hence the object on checking valid is false. Until object is valid, it wont save

Comment: @SnehaT actually, it's entirely valid, I have an enum setup, I figured out the problem too, but I can't understand why it is so, please check above.

Comment: Yeah it should work now. Is it saving?

Comment: @SnehaT yes, but the problem is, I will have some accounts without a valid user, and I can't with this condition, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You have to assign account_type some value as mentioned in schema it cannot be null...Not sure what you meant by without a valid user

Comment: @SnehaT already did in line 2 `>> a.account_type = :user`

Comment: Yeah thats what I am saying...you cannot create account with a invalid account type as it cannot be null....Thus always pass a valid account type...Only then the Account will be created and saved...

Comment: @SnehaT I've been passing a valid `account_type`, that isn't the problem at all. If you look at the update I made on the post, you'll see that the error message says `user` should be valid, while a valid `user` shouldn't be required. But I fixed it in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though Rails 5 ships with `belongs_to` being required by default, I edited the following line, and that fixed it:

```
belongs_to :user, required: false
```

[Source](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your schema, I can see that `account_type` should be an `Integer`. You are trying to save `account_type` as a `String`, see "user".

`#<Account id: nil, balance: #<BigDecimal:7f23fc3e2d68,'0.0',9(18)>, account_type: "user", user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

which is why you record returns `false` when you call `valid?`.

when assigning the `account_type` try something like so:

`a.account_type = account_type[:user]`

I am accessing your `Enums` which should assign '1' to the `account_type` field and your record should be valid and therefore save.